# Cannot align the image to the start

Tags: html, css

CSS seems too hard for me to understand while trying to learn it. Now I am using display flex, and I created a navigation bar. I want to set a background to this navbar and almost half the screen, but the image doesn't start at the most left of the screen and also some scroll bars are created. here is my code

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(79, 79, 79, 0.13);
  box-shadow: rgba(100, 100, 111, 0.2) 0px 7px 29px 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 50px;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bg-img {
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="files/images/logo.png" alt="LOGO" class="logo">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Second</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Third</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <img src="files/images/top-bg.jpg" alt="bg" class="bg-img">

</div>
```

Comment: To add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the container class would avoid the scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]In terms of the css this works:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: rgba(79, 79, 79, 0.13);
    box-shadow: rgba(100, 100, 111, 0.2) 0px 7px 29px 0px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 20px;
}

nav ul {
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.logo {
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.bg-img {
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100vw;
    opacity: 0.9;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

The problem is that you can't set a fixed padding for the navbar because of the background image. The background image also must have a fixed height to adjust it correctly. I would suggest to set the navbar to a fixed height of 75px.

Comment: this one actually works, i got also 1 more question, this background is not only for the nav its just an image behind all the elements z-index -1, now if you notice in the css of 'container' class i add a background-color but it does not show, do you know why?

Answer (score -1):

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(79, 79, 79, 0.13);
  box-shadow: rgba(100, 100, 111, 0.2) 0px 7px 29px 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 50px;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 15px;
  
}
.lp {
  float: right;
  
}

.logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header {
  background-image: url("files/images/top-bg.jpg");
  display: flex;
}
/* other code for your header bg */
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="header">
  <img src="files/images/logo.png" alt="LOGO" class="logo">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Second</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Third</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score -1):

```
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
```

This Will Select All Elements Give Actual Height and Width Not Overflow

Answer (score -1):

For your first image, I added some positioning properties to make it so it is aligned at the left, the start of the navbar. I increased the `padding` of the background image to `18.5px` so it was not in the way of the logo. And for the scrollbar, I added both `overflow: hidden` and `box-sizing: border-box` to make a hidden scrollbar and for all elements to stay in one area.

It seems as if your `display: flex` was messing with the `float` property and positioning, just a thought.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(79, 79, 79, 0.13);
  box-shadow: rgba(100, 100, 111, 0.2) 0px 7px 29px 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  left: -40px;
}


.bg-img {
  padding: 18.5px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: sticky;
  right: 1080px;
  top: -10px;
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
  <img src="files/images/logo.png" alt="LOGO" class="logo">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Second</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Third</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <img src="files/images/top-bg.jpg" alt="bg" class="bg-img">

</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope I helped. (: